# PyQt5 Signals not received from Thread after some time in QMainWindow and QWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals-slots, qthread

I have QThread where Flask app is running and serves as Webhook receiver.

```
class WebhookListenerThread(QThread):
    webhook_received = pyqtSignal(dict)
    app = Flask(__name__)

    def __init__(self):
       QThread.__init__(self)
    

    def run(self):
       
        @self.app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
        def webhook_handler():
            if request.is_json:
                webhook_data = request.json
                self.webhook_received.emit(webhook_data)
                return jsonify({'message': 'Webhook data received'}), 200
        
        self.app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Once webhook is received, it emits signal with `webhook_data`.
I have functions as slots that are connected to the signal in both of my windows, QMainWindow and QWidget.

The one in QWidget:

```
class SecondWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, webhookListener):
        super().__init__()


        self.webhookListenerThread = webhookListener
        self.webhookListenerThread.webhook_received.connect(self._handleWebhook)


    def _handleWebhook(self, webhook_data):
        if self.isVisible():
            if webhook_data['next_action'] == 'action_start':
                self._start()
            elif webhook_data['next_action'] == 'action_next':
                self._goAhead()
            elif webhook_data['next_action'] == 'action_previous':
                self._goBack()
            elif webhook_data['next_action'] == 'action_switch_off': 
                system = webhook_data['tracker']['slots']['System']
                id = webhook_data['tracker']['slots']['ID']
                ids = [...] #some predefined ids
                if id in ids:
                    self._loadAndChangeId(id, system, False) 
             
            


    def _loadAndChangeId(self, id, system, value):
        """
        make some changes in a json file
        """
        pass


    def _goAhead(self):
        """
        go to the next step, GUI changes 
        """
    
    def _goBack(self):
        """
        go to the previous step, GUI changes 
        """
 
    def _start(self):
        """
        start process and init steps
        """
        pass
```

I have the same code in `QMainWindow`.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, webhookListener):

        self.webhookListenerThread = webhookListener
        self.webhookListenerThread.webhook_received.connect(self._handleWebhook)


    def _handleWebhook(self, webhook_data):
        """
        similar to QWidget above only different webhooks
        """
        pass
    
    def _showSecondWindow(self):
        self.secondWindow = secondwindow.SecondWindow(self.webhookListenerThread)
        self.close()
        self.secondWindow.showMaximized()



def main(webhookListener):
    window = MainWindow(webhookListener)
    window.showMaximized()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    webhookListenerThread = WebhookListenerThread()
    webhookListenerThread.start()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main(webhookListenerThread)
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

It works fine most of the time, I am able to receive webhooks in both windows and changes are made according to them. However, sometimes the whole app unexpectedly crashes without any errors. While debugging I have found out that Thread works fine all the time but somehow some messages sometimes are not emitted.

I know that QWidgets are not reentrant but I am confused since it works sometimes and sometimes not? Do you see some other issue or could you simply explain me why this happens?

Comment: Are you saying that sometimes, when this signal here `self.webhook_received.emit(webhook_data)` is emitted, the app crashes? That sounds like a garbage collection problem. As you're using json, try passing a whole string instead of a dictionary, changing webhook_received to a pyqtSignal(str), and convert data from "json string" to "python object" on the main thread, inside the signal listener. If this doesn't solve your problem, I don't know what is it, you may need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem.